# How do i access the object after i defined its binding with braces?

Tags: javascript, ecmascript-6, destructuring

I used the method described below to access a property of an object by the binding of the object but how do i access the object now?

```
   var {emri}={emri:"Arjon",mosha:23};
   >emri
   <"Arjon"
   >emri.mosha
   <undefined
```

Comment: Simple: don't use destructuring when you want the whole object.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can't.

The `{emri:"Arjon",mosha:23}` object's lifetime was only this statement:

```
 var {emri}={emri:"Arjon",mosha:23};
```

If you don't keep a reference to an object, it's freed, you can't access it anymore. And there's no reference from a value to its origin.

Answer (score 2):

The `var {test} = obj` that mean you will create a variable and assign value with `test` property of obj `object`, if you declare object before you still can use it.

```js
var obj ={emri:"Arjon", test: 9.5, mosha:23};

var {test} = obj;

console.log(typeof(test) + " : " + test)

console.log(obj);
```